# Is there any way to remove duplicate Windows firewall rules with a script or some app

Tags: windows

I have a PC with a lot of firewall rules, and a lot of them are duplicates. I have like 5 of the exact same rule. Will this cause some sort of conflict?

Is there any kind of script that anyone has or some program that can get rid of these duplicate rules?

Comment: Are you aware that the windows firewall always has all rules 3 times (for the different network types Private, Public and Domain)?

Answer (score 2):

I created a powershell script to remove duplicate firewall rules. But since it uses the firewall management cmdlets, it may not run on old versions of Windows. But anyway, you can give it a try.

```
# Here we use `netsh advfirewall firewall show` to get all firewall rules, since it's way faster than Get-NetFirewallRule!!!!!!!
$output = (netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=all verbose | Out-String).Trim() -split '\r?\n\s*\r?\n'
$propertyNames = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()

$objects = @( $(foreach($section in $output ) {
    $obj = @{}

    foreach( $line in ($section -split '\r?\n') ) {
        if( $line -match '^\-+$' ) { continue }
        $name, $value = $line -split ':\s*', 2
        $name = $name -replace " ", ""
        
        $obj.$name  = $value
        if($propertyNames -notcontains $name) {
            $propertyNames.Add( $name )
        }
    }
    $obj
}) | % {
    foreach( $prop in $propertyNames ) {
        if( $_.Keys -notcontains $prop ) {
            $_.$prop = $null
        }
    }
    [PSCustomObject]$_
})

$r = $objects | Group-Object -Property RuleName, Program, Action, Profiles, RemoteIP, RemotePort, LocalIP, LocalPort, Enabled, Protocol, Direction
# If you want to take a look
# $r | ?{$_.Count -gt 1} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty group | Out-GridView

$r | ?{$_.Count -gt 1} | %{
    $name = $_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty group | Select-Object -ExpandProperty RuleName -First 1
    # Here we have to use this cmdlet, since `netsh advfirewall firewall delete` can't differentiate rules with the same names and will delte them all! 
    Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName $name | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Remove-NetFirewallRule
}
```

Comment: Verified this on Win10 and Win11 - have a few apps that like to abusively make sure their port is available.

Comment: @Joe You mean my script works or not? I'm sorry I'm not native English speaker. I don't quite understand your comment.

Comment: It worked great.

Comment: does not seem to work for me. I still have dozens of identical firewall rules after running the script

Comment: For some reason, the filter `| ?{$_.Count -gt 1}` causes nothing to be processed. I removed that (from two places in the script) and then the script did its thing.

Note that:
- It must be run as Administrator
- It takes quite a while to run
- If you want to see some output while it's progressing, you can add
  `echo $name` just after the `$name = ` assignment

TY much to the author! 
Also, amazing how much crap accumulates there over the years!

Answer (score 1):

I would use PowerShell's `Remove-NetFirewallRule` to automate these types of actions; if it is just five rules, you can identify the rules and remove them, but if you have a lot more, you should figure out why you have them in the first place - did you try to install an application five times, or is it from an update?

- If you don't use an IDE like Visual Code, PowerShell ISE will help with writing and executing PowerShell scripts
- You can find PowerShell scripts that use `Remove-NetFirewallRule`, such as [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/akgbsq/powershell_firewall_rules_cleaner/) one

Comment: It's actually hundreds of duplicate rules; I mentioned 5 duplicates as in 5 copies of one rule; and I have hundreds of rules with hundreds of duplicates that are there.   I don't exactly know what caused this in the first place, as this isn't my PC but I can guess that someone used an batch processor or something to add firewall rules to every exe and dll within a folder and did that multiple times, as I can see a lot of the same .bat file that does this.